# How to integrate twitter API in iphone SDK in such a way that the I can enter user name and password through my own defined UITextFields?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

In my iphone app, I am having a twitter page where the user is entering his username and Password.Here, the problem is that I want to enter it from my own defined textFields like this example.How should I do it using SA_OAuth library.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkRTVFj6XaA.

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks
Prajnaranjan Das

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video you pointed to is about their old authentication mechanism, but you need to read up on their new authentication.

There is a twitter client that uses XAuth (instead of OAuth), which allows you to present native username/password fields:

```
https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter
```

And a library for using OAuth itself with Twitter:

```
https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone
```

Comment: Thank for your reply @Kirstein.I checked the first link and replaced the Consumer key and Consumer secret key but when I am signing in its coming back to the same page.Can you please tell me how should I see my updates through this project in Twitter.

Thanks 
Prajnaranjan Das

Comment: The XAuth authentication requires that you get special permission from Twitter to use XAuth.  It won't work if you just get a developer key - I would suggest using the second one with OAuth to get something working more quickly (as Twitter needs to explicitly set your key for XAuth).

Answer (score 1):

A newer, more comprehensive Twitter 1.1 wrapper for Objective-C:

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter